# Time/Date Stamp on Google Drive Permission Update Change???? (Does anyone know?)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I wondered if anyone can advise as to whether there is a date/time stamp captured when user permissions are updated on files located within Google Drive?

There doesn't seem to be anything listed to this end in: 
https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/update

Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you already checked if the file modified date changes?

Answer (score 0):

When you list permissions or when you get a specific permission, the API provides an `ETag` field which works like a timestamp :

```
{
 "kind": "drive#permissionList",
 "etag": "\"sIP8ArR2PAy9qIx8FYkTpbHmKik/nJ62bPlkoRJd-M_nZE_16ustISo\"",
 "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/13oJ5-WwSHlo_7ihh6mCiRSAnm-1NVCERTHNpNYHou54/permissions",
 "items": [
  {

   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "\"sIP8ArR2PAy9qIx8FYkTpbHmKik/IvARrqkP42sg1PAxAPG7aLj6j2k\"",
   "id": "XXXXXXX",
   "selfLink": "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/13oJ5-XXXXXX",
   "name": "XXXX",
   "emailAddress": "XXXXX",
   "domain": "gmail.com",
   "role": "owner",
   "type": "user",
   "photoLink": "XXXXX"
  },
  {

   "kind": "drive#permission",
   "etag": "\"sIP8ArR2PAy9qIx8FYkTpbHmKik/JBxs7HICtZb-IpV7hqg-y3WbKzI\"",
   "id": "XXXXX",
   "selfLink": "XXXXX",
   "name": "XXXX",
   "emailAddress": "XXXX",
   "domain": "gmail.com",
   "role": "writer",
   "type": "user",
   "photoLink": "XXXXX"
  }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `modifiedDate` field of the [Files resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) changes when the permissions are changed for that file.